# Get Monitor Screen size using javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there any calculation I can use with javascript which can get me Users monitor size i.e 15'' 17'' etc.
I can get screen resoution using

screen.width * screen.height

Comment: Only if you know pixel density.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window

Answer (score 0):

You can use this I would imagine

```
var width = screen.availWidth/72;
var height = screen.availHeight/72;
```

the 72 comes for 72ppi and basically you would get the width and height assuming the user has the screen at the max resolution.

The inches would be virtual basically if they don't have it at max resolution.  But it would work the same because the available space would still be what you have to work with.